# Gevent async server with blocking requests

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, gevent

I have what I would think is a pretty common use case for Gevent. I need a UDP server that listens for requests, and based on the request submits a POST to an external web service. The external web service essentially only allows one request at a time.

I would like to have an asynchronous UDP server so that data can be immediately retrieved and stored so that I don't miss any requests (this part is easy with the DatagramServer gevent provides). Then I need some way to send requests to the external web service serially, but in such a way that it doesn't ruin the async of the UDP server.

I first tried monkey patching everything and what I ended up with was a quick solution, but one in which my requests to the external web service were not rate limited in any way and which resulted in errors.

It seems like what I need is a single non-blocking worker to send requests to the external web service in serial while the UDP server adds tasks to the queue from which the non-blocking worker is working.

What I need is information on running a gevent server with additional greenlets for other tasks (especially with a queue). I've been using the `serve_forever` function of the DatagramServer and think that I'll need to use the `start` method instead, but haven't found much information on how it would fit together.

Thanks,

**EDIT**

The answer worked very well. I've adapted the [UDP server example](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/blob/master/examples/udp_server.py) code with the answer from @mguijarr to produce a working example for my use case:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from gevent.server import DatagramServer
import gevent.queue
import gevent.monkey
import urllib

gevent.monkey.patch_all()

n = 0

def process_request(q):
    while True:
        request = q.get()
        print(request)
        print(urllib.urlopen('https://test.com').read())


class EchoServer(DatagramServer):
    __q = gevent.queue.Queue()
    __request_processing_greenlet = gevent.spawn(process_request, __q)

    def handle(self, data, address):
        print('%s: got %r' % (address[0], data))
        global n
        n += 1
        print(n)
        self.__q.put(n)
        self.socket.sendto('Received %s bytes' % len(data), address)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Receiving datagrams on :9000')
    EchoServer(':9000').serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

1. Write a function taking a "queue" object as argument; this function will continuously process items from the queue. Each item is supposed to be a request for the web service.
   This function could be a module-level function, not part of your DatagramServer instance:

   ```
   def process_requests(q):
       while True:
           request = q.get()
           # do your magic with 'request'
           ...
   ```
2. in your DatagramServer, make the function running within a greenlet (like a background task):

   ```
   self.__q = gevent.queue.Queue()
   self.__request_processing_greenlet = gevent.spawn(process_requests, self.__q)
   ```
3. when you receive the UDP request in your DatagramServer instance, you push the request to the queue

   ```
   self.__q.put(request)
   ```

This should do what you want. You still call 'serve_forever' on DatagramServer, no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: Code worked beautifully. I've updated my question with the working example code from the UDP server example and your solution. Thanks!